# Tool to inspect a XAP (Windows Phone app) file

Tags: windows-phone, decompiler

I am looking for a tool to extract from a [XAP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XAP_%28file_format%29) (Windows Phone app) file:

- Metadata such as version name, libraries, etc
- String resources
- Binary resources
- Dialog definitions
- Ideally: decompiled source code

Ideally running on Linux, other systems acceptable.

Context: I have released an Android app under the GNU-GPL, and today a user reported that there is a Windows Phone that looks exactly the same, exact same strings etc. I would like to check the strings resources and dialogs in more detail, and even the disassembled source code if possible, to check whether they just re-created the app or just ported it, which would violate the GNU-GPL as they did not release the modified source code.